I face error when trying to login using linkedin
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=77t3int9oa8i8b&redirect_uri=http://localhost/linkedin/login.php&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress&state=49506
i get the error
Bummer, something went wrong.
In five seconds, you will be redirected to: localhost whenever i try to go login with the above url. i aleady allowed  all neccessary authorization and my uri matches.
Is something wrong with the integration of LinkedIn login? Highly appreciate your support to fix the issue.
I dont understand what is the issue. Have tried almost everything available on google including contacting the brainless support team but in vain.

Have you paid any attention to the parameters in the localhost URL you are getting redirected back to yet ...?

I think so the problem with the scopes your using .. check with the official documentation.. u just need to use scope=profile... like this


Firstly, that documentation would have been better included as a quotation-block in which each line is prefixed with the > character. If it's official documentation, it also has a link. Secondly, answer as it stands doesn't say how to fix the scope. It just says to check the documentation.
